# How to insert fetched value and newly entered values in table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using two buttons "Fetch" and "Submit" in the same page. When I click "Fetch" button am getting the values from one table[ticketgeneration] and display in the form, and fetch is working fine.  My working url - https://sampledemos.online/callreports/details.php. In this when I input the ticket ID as "Sample123" and when I click Fetch button it will fetch and display the details till "Call Type" from "ticketgeneration" table. After the field "Call Type" am entering new values for the remaining fields. Now all the values [both fetched and newly enter values] needs to insert in the table "details".

```
HTML Section
<div class="col-sm-3">
             <center><input type="submit" name="fetch" id="fetch" class="btn btn-primary" value="Fetch Records" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;float:right;"></center>
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
                <center><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;float:left;"></center>
        </div>
```

```
PHP Section
for fetching records
if (isset($_POST['fetch'])) {
       $ticketid1 = $_POST['tid'];
        $sel = "select * from ticketgeneration where ticket_id='$ticketid1'";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sel);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        
    }
```

The above code is fetching the values from "ticketgeneration" table and display in the textbox

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="custname" id="custname" value="<?php echo $row['customer_name'];?>">
```

```
Insert Section

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $ticketgendate = $_POST['date'];
       $ticketid = $row['ticket_id'];
        $customername = $row['customer_name'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $reportedby = $row['problem_reported_by'];
       $contactnumber = $row['contact_no'];
       $mailid = $row['mail_id'];
        $reported = $row['problem_reported_by'];
        $proddetails = $row['product_details'];
        $sernum = $row['product_serial_number'];
        $calltype = $row['call_type'];
        $callmode = $_POST['callmode'];
        $assignedto = $_POST['assign'];
        $diag = $_POST['diag'];
        $actiontaken  = $_POST['action'];
        $callstatus = $_POST['callstatus'];
        $reason =    $_POST['reason'];
        $callrepno = $_POST['repno'];
        $servicecost = $_POST['service'];
        $sparecost = $_POST['spare'];
        $billingamt = $_POST['billamt'];
        $followup = $_POST['followup']; 
        $from = $_POST['from'];
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $starttime = $_POST['stime'];
        $endtime = $_POST['etime'];
        $reviewedby = $_POST['revby'];
        $comments = $_POST['comment'];

$ins = "insert into details (date,ticket_id,customer_name,location,problem_reported_by,contact_no,mail_id,problem_reported,product_details,product_serial_number,call_type,call_mode,assigned_to,diag,action,status,reason,report_no,service,spare,billing,follow,from_,to_,start_time,end_time,reviewed_by,comments) values ('$ticketgendate','$ticketid','$customername','$location','$reportedby','$contactnumber','$mailid','$reported','$proddetails','$sernum','$calltype', '$callmode','$assignedto','$diag','$actiontaken','$callstatus','$reason','$callrepno','$servicecost','$sparecost','$billingamt','$followup','$from','$to','$starttime','$endtime',' $reviewedby','$comments')";
```

Is my insert query statement is correct for inserting both fetched and newly entered values into the table "details"

Comment: what's with all this `....` thing in your insert statement? they are not correct if you are directly executing the one you showed us.

Comment: _"Is my insert query statement is correct for inserting both fetched and newly entered values into the table "details""_ Have you tried running the code?

Comment: @waanofii.tech I have edited my question and placed all my insert queries... where $row[values] are fetched values from one table and $_POST[] are newly entered values. I need both these values to be inserted in details table.  is my insert query part correct..

Comment: Please include what errors you get in the question

Comment: Then you need to turn on error reporting,

Comment: first turn on the error reporting by `error_reporting(0);`function at the top of the page. then do this `if(mysqli_query($conn,$ins){ echo "successfull"; } else { echo myqli_error($conn); }` and definitely you will see an error then show us the error.NOTE: I assumed your db connection link to be `$conn` replace it with yours. @Venkat

Comment: Thanks @waanofii.tech i got message as successfull..so is my insert query part is correct..url screenshot- https://sampledemos.online/callreports/1.png - I used `$res = mysqli_query($conn,$ins);
        if($res) { echo "successfull"; } else { echo myqli_error($conn); }`

Comment: @Venkat you are widely open to sql injection if you are not sanitizing your input before inserting. Consider using mysqli_real_escape_string at least. but it's recommended if you used prepared statement.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: Thanks all  .... values are inserted.. I got all the fetch values and assigned to $_POST[] and used normal insert query ... Thanks all for your valuable time